# Find multiple of 'radius' of square given angle of line.

Tags: geometry

Sorry for the odd title, I couldn't think of anything better. Feel free to rename. Anyway, I'm trying to find a formula that takes an angle (i.e. $60^\circ$) and gives out a certain value.

The angle is an angle of a ray extending from an arbitrary point. (Using $\left(\,0,0\,\right)$ makes it simple.) That point is also the center of a square where the shortest distance from that point to any point on any side of the square is some measured value, which I describe as the "radius" of the square.

I need a formula that finds out what multiple of the "radius" the line must travel before crossing the border of the square. From what I have found, when the line is $0^\circ, 90^\circ, 180^\circ,\ \mbox{or}\ 270^\circ$ the multiple is, obviously, $1$, and when the angle is $45^\circ, 135^\circ, 225^\circ\ \mbox{or}\ 315^\circ$ it is $1\frac{1}{2}$. Now L'm trying to figure out an equation that takes an angle and tells me that multiple.

I made a few equations, but none of them worked and I can't say I totally know what i'm doing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{2}$ if the angle is $45^\circ$?

Comment: $\min(|\sec(x)|,|\csc(x)|)$ looks good

Comment: using desmos graphing calculator with that equation gives me 1.119... not 1 when x is 90.

Comment: @user1825860 Then it's probably in radians, not degrees.

Comment: @user1825860: $\csc(90)=1.11857$ so you are using radians. $90^\circ=\frac\pi2$ radians. As with any calculator, you need to set the mode to reflect the angular units you are using (degrees or radians).

Answer (score 2):

Considering the following diagram

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

it appears that $\min\left(|\sec(x)|,|\csc(x)|\right)$ is the function you want.

Comment: For those who have a different radius than 1, where r is the radius from 0, 90, 180, or 270 degrees to edge and d is the end distance, r * min(| sec(x) |, | csc(x) |) = d. Live demo - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hl26g2nijg

Comment: The question was what multiple of the radius. The answer works for any radius.

Comment: Your completely right and I think you misunderstood my comment. You have to multiply the radius by your original formula which is all I added. The radius should be at the angle 0, 90, etc.. which in your example is 1.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $\sqrt{2}\approx1.41421$ for $45^\circ$ angles.

The answer is $\sec({\theta})$ where $-45^\circ\le\theta\le45^\circ$. ($\theta$ is the angle.) If $\theta$ is anything else, subtract $90^\circ$ until it's in that range.

($\sec$ is something you will learn about/have learned about in trigonometry.)

Graph:[image: Graph]

EDIT: As someone pointed out, a formula that works for every $\theta$ is:$$\min(\left|\sec(\theta)\right|,\left|\csc(\theta)\right|)$$If you want to test this out, check that your calculator is on degrees.